# Converting Piecewise function to C code

Tags: piecewise, code-generation

I'm trying to convert a function to C Code

`f = D[Piecewise[{{x^2, -10 < x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], x]`

I decided to scan through conditions and corresponding output formulas, but the conditions are not expressed in proper form.

For example element `f[[1]][[2, 2]]` is

`-10 < x < 0 // CForm`

`Inequality(-10,Less,x,Less,0)`

Which looks nothing like a proper C Form. However inequality with one side:

`f[[1]][[1, 2]] // CForm`

Gives a proper string

`x < -10`

How do I get the proper form like `x>-10&&x<0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-10 < x < 0 // LogicalExpand // CForm

(* -10 < x && x < 0 *)
```